# How to efficiently configure Azure DevOps repo policies and branch permissions?

Tags: git, azure-devops

My department recently changed to git. At the end of it all, we have well over 100 repos. Is there a tool or easy to use command-line option of copying settings?

I have looked at the REST API around security and repos but it's not easily decipherable. You have to set the specific flag bit values and identity SIDs in a non-intuitive way. Further, the documentation doesn't explain what the bit values mean. I'm pretty sure if I use that method, something is going to get messed up.

Are there any alternatives outside manually configuring hundreds of settings?

Comment: @Matt all settings and policies are the same across all repos in a given team project so kinda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid this feature is not supported in Azure DevOps at present. According to your description, I think you are actually in need of a branch policy template feature, and then you can use this template in other repos or branches without setting them one by one.

There have been many committers who have suggested this feature and Microsoft has accepted this feature request. This feature will be updated in subsequent Azure DevOps versions. You can follow this suggestion ticket for updates.

Here is the suggestion ticket [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/365824/have-branch-police-template-to-store-the-branch-po.html).

Comment: That sucks, but I appreciate an answer. Would it be possible in the meantime to release a translation shim in your API to at least describe a permission value and translate SIDs? So, I want to specify permissions and it tells me the bit value of that permission set. I could also give the group name instead of the SID. This would let the security API be much more usable. It's not that I don't want to use it, it's simply too arcane as is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this doesn't get you all the way to where you want to be, but the security model in Azure DevOps allows for inherited [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-git-tfvc-repository-permissions?view=azure-devops#set-git-repository-permissions).  If you were to set permissions at the 'Git repository' level, all your repositories configured with inheritance enabled should assume those privileges.  If you want something more granular with permissions defined one way on a *master* branch or another on *develop* across all repos, this won't work.

[image]

Comment: Right. This part isn't so difficult. The annoying part is that policies are per branch per repo. You can't inherit policies across repos or branches as far as I'm aware.